# Composer Class loading: Doesn't find classes

Tags: php, composer-php

**Hi there,**

I'm fairly new in working with composer, but I'm experiencing issues. After some stackoverflow searches I tried some of te solutions, however, none of them did work for me. I Have the following error:

`Fatal error: Class 'Freeby\Basic\Navigator' not found in index.php on line *`.

So I took a look at my index. It contains the following code:
**index.php**

```
namespace Freeby;

use \Freeby\Basic\Navigator as Navigator;

Navigator::execute();
```

The line where the error occurs is the last one, `Navigator::execute();`. So I went to take a look at this class found in the folder `Basic`. **Navigator.php**

```
namespace Freeby\Basic;

class Navigator
{

    public static function execute()
    {

    }

}
```

So, I have my namespace there. It should be recognized. However, it does not. So I went on to check my **composer.json**.

```
{
    "require": {
        "mikecao/flight": "^1.3"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Freeby\\Basic\\": "Basic/"
        }
    }
}
```

And I think this one is correct. However I'm not that sure. To be sure I'll include my structure here too. Maybe it's a path issue? If yes, why? I Couldn't find it.

```
---- Basic
- Navigator.php
---- Vendor
- autoload.php
-- composer
---- composer.json
```

Comment: `use Basic\Navigator as Navigator;` you're already in the `Freeby` namespace. At least I think thats right. You also wouldn't need `as Navigator` because `Navigator` is already assumed.

Comment: @castis Hey. I've tried this, and it will not fix the issue. I will keep the same error, plus additionally my IDE will say that the namespace `basic` isn't defined.

Comment: ahh bummer, I should brush up on my php knowledge! i know might be obvious but you ran `composer dump-autoload` already? just covering bases

Comment: @castis Indeed. I've done it multiple times. Yes, it's good to cover the base.

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to load the composer autoloader first in `index.php`

```
<?php

namespace Freeby;

require __DIR__."/vendor/autoload.php";

use \Freeby\Basic\Navigator as Navigator;

Navigator::execute();
```